# Esri Android Basemap with kml

Tags: android, arcgis

I created a kml using the kmllayer. When I set the map with a basemap and use the addLayer() method the kml is not shown. I can see the kml layer without a basemap. Can someone post sample code on using basemap with kml? am using ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer as basemap

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I got past it by adding the KMLLayer after the map is initialized. Here's my code.

```
ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer dynamicLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(mapUrl);

map.addLayer(dynamicLayer);
map.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(Object object, STATUS status) {
        if (status == OnStatusChangedListener.STATUS.INITIALIZED) {
            map.addLayer(new KMLLayer("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2654618/kml/Wyoming.kml", map.getSpatialReference()));
        }
    }
});
```

Its also worth noting that the ESRI documentation states that "Locally hosted or KML files inside a firewall are not supported."

Comment: Hi, this solution did not work for me. I added `kmlLink.refresh(); kmlLink.setVisible(true);` after `STATUS.INITIALIZED` too. Does anyone have other suggestions?